# SeoUrl and .htacces settings

Tags: .htaccess, url, seo

I try to make my site run with seo when i access
**mysite.com/search/eminem/1/video.html** 
to give me the results for this url 
**mysite.com/index.php?search=eminem&page=1&type=video**
And it show me the search page but with no results no images or javascripts etc. Is like css and js's are not implemented

this is my .htacces code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/(.*)/(.*).html?$ index.php?search=$3&page=$2&type=$1 [L]
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
        <FilesMatch "\.(php|js|css|mp3|wmv|flv|html|htm)$">
            SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: your rule is file. 1-try adding `RewriteBase /`. 2- what's the error code?

Comment: I look at the console errors in google chrome. Is not showing any errors. Is like css and js are not even included in my index.php or it jumps directly to search.php withouth takeing the index.php and this is how i include search.php in my index.php `<?php

if (isset($_GET['search'])) include('search.php');
else include('templates/home.php'); 
?>`

Comment: I tryed RewriteBase / and still the same. And another thing. my site and .htaccess file is in mysite.com/test/ directory but i dont think this can be the cause or if it is please let me know.

Comment: is there any other rule in your htaccess file?

Comment: no my htaccess file is exacty like i posted. I am using ubuntu server and i have another script that works great with seo rewrite.

Comment: Let me know if I'm right:`.htaccess` file is in document root, has no other rules and your problem is that search page is shown without images,css,scripts..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to make all your relative links (for images, CSS, JavaScript, etc)  to absolute links with a leading slash, or add this to the header of your index.php content:

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: Jon Lin i tryed your code. Not working. is like it dont take in consideration index.php and jump directly to search.php and css and javascripts are not included. i just get the search html with no decoration or any scripts running. and when i click search i get the url like this `mysite.com/search/eminem/1/video.html?search=eminem&page=1&type=video`

Comment: I found the problem was from my apache2 server. Thanks for your code Jon Lin it is very useful